# Pause/Resume Upload in C#

Tags: c#, upload, webclient

I'm looking for a way to pause or resume an upload process via C#'s WebClient.

pseudocode:

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient();
Client.UploadFileAsync(new Uri("http://mysite.com/receiver.php"), "POST", "C:\MyFile.jpg");
```

Maybe something like..

```
Client.Pause();
```

any idea?

Comment: Agree with Jon! I actually opened this question because I was curious to see how C# and PHP are getting along ;)

Answer (score 6):

`WebClient` doesn't have this kind of functionality - even the slightly-lower-level `HttpWebRequest` doesn't, as far as I'm aware. You'll need to use an HTTP library which gives you more control over *exactly* when things happen (which will no doubt involve more code as well, of course). The point of `WebClient` is to provide a very simple API to use in very simple situations.

Answer (score 3):

As stated by Jon Skeet, this is not available in the Webclient not HttpWebRequest classes.

However, if you have control of the server, that receives the upload; perhaps you could upload small chunks of the file using WebClient, and have the server assemble the chunks when all has been received. Then it would be somewhat easier for you to make a Pause/resume functionality.

If you do not have control of the server, you will need to use an API that gives you mere control, and subsequently gives you more stuff to worry about. And even then, the server might give you a time-out if you pause for too long.

Answer (score 2):

ok, with out giving you code examples I will tell you what you can do.

Write a WCF service for your upload, that service needs to use streaming.

things to remember:

- client and server needs to identify
  the file some how i suggest the use
  of a Guid so the server knows what
  file to append the extra data too.
- Client needs to keep track of
  position in the array so it knows
  where to begin the streaming after it
  resumes it. (you can even get the
  server to tell the client how much
  data it has but make sure the client
  knows too).
- Server needs to keep track of how
  much data it has already downloaded
  and how much still missing. files
  should have a life time on the
  server, you dont want half uploaded
  and forgotten files stored on the
  server forever.
- please remember that, streaming does
  not allow authentication since the
  whole call is just one httprequest.
  you can use ssl but remember that
  will add a overhead.
- you will need to create the service
  contract at message level standard
  method wont do.

I currently writing a Blog post about the very subject, It will be posted this week with code samples for how to get it working.

you can check it on [My blog](http://undocnet.blogspot.com)

I know this does not contain code samples but the blog will have some but all in all this is one way of doing stop and resume of file uploads to a server.

Answer (score 0):

To do something like this you must write your own worker thread that does the actual http post stepwise.

Before sending a you have to check if the operation is paused and stop sending file content until it is resumed.

However depending on the server the connection can be closed if it isn't active for certain period of time and this can be just couple of seconds.