# Resume in upload file control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, file-upload

I did read the following posts:

1. [Pause/Resume Upload in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048330/pause-resume-upload-in-c)
2. [resume uploads using HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830130/resume-uploads-using-http)

But didn't got a perfect solution to my problem.

1. In the above posts, one of the answers says `"client and server needs to identify the file some how i suggest the use of a Guid so the server knows what file to append the extra data too."` Request you to plz visit the first link of the aobve and find that answer. This answer is all about streaming. Can someone plz provide links using which I can build such kind of code?
2. In these posts one of the answer said `"you can send several small file pieces and rebuild them server side"`...**HOW**?
3. Can't I use something like `checksum` etc to detect how much part is uploaded and how much more needs to be and append it to that file? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3):

1. [Streams](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/04/14/streams.html) are a fairly fundemental concept in working with files on the .NET platform (as it is in Java, C and other languages). You should start by reading about them and how to use them. See the [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) class on MSDN.
2. HOW? By using streaming - you stream parts of the file, in small chunks (using an offset into the file and the size of chunk). Again, see [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) documentation.
3. You could, but checksums of different files may be the same - with a GUID the chance of a [collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Properties) is pretty small compared to checksums.

Comment: +1 For answering all the questions...
But could u plz elaborate more about the (3) point. How can I achieve my requirements using GUID method, links to code etc?