# Form upload queries

Tags: asp.net, html, file-upload

I am a newbie and have a requirement to upload ~2GB files via form upload.

I am unsure whether the 2GB file will be received as a whole on the "action URL" - (http://localhost:49980/videoupload.aspx) page or will it be received in parts/chunks?

Thanks in advance for clarifying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly [Increasing the Maximum Upload Size](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx)

The 4MB default is set in machine.config, but you can override it in you web.config. For instance, to expand the upload limit to 20MB, you'd do this:

Then upload your file in chunk of bytes. [ASP.Net: Writing chunks of file..HTTP File upload with resume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069880/asp-net-writing-chunks-of-file-http-file-upload-with-resume) and [Upload Large Files in ASP.NET Using HttpModule](http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/haissam/archive/2008/09/12/upload-large-files-in-asp-net-using-httpmodule.aspx).

you can go for this: [Recommendations for best ASP.NET file upload tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366172/recommendations-for-best-asp-net-file-upload-tool)

For Reference:
[Streaming large file uploads to ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046230/streaming-large-file-uploads-to-asp-net-mvc)
[Multiple File Upload With Progress Bar Using Flash and ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15742/Multiple-File-Upload-With-Progress-Bar-Using-Flash)
[Upload large files in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285120/upload-large-files-in-net)