# Visual Basic 2013 HttpWebRequest

Tags: vb.net, http, visual-studio-2013, web-scraping

I've made my Visual Basic 2013, Internet Downloader windows form Application 
It's working and downloading but i want to add a Pause / Resume Buttons

```
Dim theResponse As HttpWebResponse
    Dim theRequest As HttpWebRequest
        theRequest = WebRequest.Create(Me.txtFileName1.Text)
        theResponse = theRequest.GetResponse

    If Me.BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then
        IO.File.Delete(Me.whereToSave)
        Dim cancelDelegate As New DownloadCompleteSafe(AddressOf DownloadComplete)
        Me.Invoke(cancelDelegate, True)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim completeDelegate As New DownloadCompleteSafe(AddressOf DownloadComplete)

        Me.Invoke(completeDelegate, False)
```

but it only can Cancel and Resume

```
Me.BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync() 
Me.BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
```

How can I make a Pause and Resume Backgroundworker HTTPWebRequest pause the download and resume it later?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pause/Resume Upload in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048330/pause-resume-upload-in-c-sharp)